# How do I add a source controlled (tfs) project to a solution and maintain binding?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, tfs, visual-studio-2013

I would like to create three separate ASP.NET MVC solutions, all pointing to the same Model project.  How do I keep changes made from one solution update the others?

Ex, is there is way in Visual Studio to "Add new project from Source Control" like you can with a whole solution?

Comment: Shared source is a very bad practice and will increase the likelihood of bugs and errors. You should always share binaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you are hoping to have 3 solutions that share a common project.

You can achieve this in 2 ways.

**NuGet**
Have the project in it's own solution and create a NuGet package of the output, your other solutions can then consume the NuGet Package.

**Shared Project**
A shared project is easy to do, just ensure that your shared project is available in the same workspace as your solutions.Do a get latest, You can then just right click on the solution and choose add existing project. 
Any changes you make will need to be checked back into source control, these changes will then appear in each 'copy' of the project in each of the different solutions.

The shared project works fine, but you may have to make some considerations when you come to building the solutions, the main one being that if you only make a change to the shared project would you want all of the solutions that consume it to be built on check-in?

Comment: We're not doing automated builds on this, so no.  Thanks for the thought on that.